# pingdom sacking my site's resources

Tags: .htaccess, http, ping

It appears that somebody created a pingdom account to ping my site once a minute, and since my website isn't hosted on a very strong server anyway, those requests get heavy and slow down the server, will blocking pingdom's servers through `.htaccess` help? will it use less resources then when pingdom just downloads my entire homepage?
and if it will, is there a way to block them based on user agent? their IP always changes, but the user agent stay the same `Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http://www.pingdom.com/)`

Comment: Why are you posting here? You should be contacting Pingdom.

Comment: i tried, no response.

Comment: Try contacting them via an @reply on public twitter.  If they think their brand image is at risk they'll probably be more likely to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it via iptables.

Pingdom have a specific set of IP addresses they use,  and,  unsurprisingly, make the list public.

https://support.pingdom.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/16/0/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-ip-addresses-for-the-pingdom-probe-servers

You could retrieve the list, and script the process of creating iptables drop rules for them.